# Bulk load of tables from SQL Server into snowflake

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to copy tables in various schemas from SQL Server to snowflake. I understand that snowflake COPY works well to load huge amount of data into snowflake, provided I have CSV data as input.

However, I am unable to figure out an efficient way to export SQL Server data in CSV format. I went through some of the threads in this forum on this topic and found that PowerShell tool export-csv is a good option. But does it work well with thousands of tables in SQL Server?

If not, what other option should I try to move the data from SQL Server to snowflake? Please note that this is not a one time data load. I am looking for a process that can run daily to load data from SQL Server to snowflake.

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I tried the SQL Server `bcp` tool. But it doesn't generate a standardized CSV file.

Comment: SSIS is specifically designed for tasks like this.

Comment: @allmhuran, Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have SSIS.

Comment: In that case bcp is a good option. You said it doesn't generate a "standardized" CSV file, but bcp has [quite a few formatting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) (like selection of field terminator, row terminator, code page, etc). What specifically is the problem you are having with the output format?

Comment: @allmhuran, if I keep delimiter as comma and the data has comma in it, how does bcp handles this scenario?

Comment: If you insist on using comma as a separator, you can use a [format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). But if I were you, I wouldn't follow the lemmings off the cliff and treat the "C" in "CSV" as meaning "comma", because commas are terrible as field separators, for the reason you've identified. Think of the "C" as meaning "character", and use tabs, or some other character that is much less likely to appear in your data.

Comment: @allmhuran, I tried using ascii unit character as separator. However, the data contains ascii unit character as well. The data contains tab as well.

Comment: Your data contains ascii 31 and tabs? That's gotta be the dirtiest data ever. Presumably you also have quotes and commas, so quoted comma separated would be a nightmare. You might be better off using multiple characters in sequence as a separator, like ####, or |||| or something like that. bcp will let you do that.

Comment: If you have special characters and control characters in your data, just escape them. Typically the backslash character is the escape, and if you have a backslash in the data the escape sequence \\ takes care of that. So you could use commas as a separator as long as you replace them inside the data with \,

Comment: SQL Server should also wrap double-quotes around fields that contain the delimiter, which Snowflake can undo on the way into Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

BCP is usually the fastest and really simple tool to get data out of SQL server into a CSV file. If your data contains commas, you can qualify the text with double quotes so the import sees the commas as part of the data. In the past, I have used BCP with the query out option to replace these troubled characters on export as well. Going from a CSV file into Snowflake has been problematic for me. I have found that even trying to send CSV files into an S3 bucket and loading them into Snowflake is too slow for our needs.

I have found a tool called SQLpipe that does most of that work for me in a direct connection between one data source and another.
I have been very successful using SQLpipe to copy data from SQL server into Snowflake. It works well with PostgreSQL to Snowflake as well. I would skip trying to export to a CSV and then copy and import into Snowflake.

SQLPipe - https://www.sqlpipe.com/
Here is a statement from their website. “Our original product, SQLpipe, is an open-source tool that allows you to move the results of a SQL query from any ODBC compliant data source, to a target data system.”

I hope that helps! Good luck!